# Do I require a partition key when dealing with the CosmosDB emulator?

Tags: .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

Trying to delete a CosmosDB document via DeleteDocumentAsync is giving me a Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException: Message: {"Errors":["Resource Not Found"]} no matter what I try.
I am using the CosmosDB local emulator with a single collection and a single record for now, so I haven't defined any partition key.

This is my document structure:

```
{
"id": "a1032017-c131-4fe0-a045-1d342bc56410",
"Code": "059058",
"Key": "f9971f3a-9737-4da5-90df-2ab7f93ba679",
"CreatedOn": "2019-09-30T15:50:53.0368614-04:00",
"TTL": 1440,
"PhoneNumber": "1112223333",
"_rid": "35E3AOfSiUUBAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/35E3AA==/colls/35E3AOfSiUU=/docs/35E3AOfSiUUBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-77c8-620aa5ca01d5\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1569873059
```

}

Code to delete:

```
public async Task Delete<T>(T codeKeyPairModel) where T : CodeKeyPairModel
    {
        var documentLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(cosmosDBId, collectionId, codeKeyPairModel.Id.ToString());
        var result = await cosmosDBClient.DeleteDocumentAsync(documentLink,
                new RequestOptions() { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(Undefined.Value) });
    }
```

documentLink value:

```
{dbs/CodeCheckerDB/colls/CodeKeyPair/docs/a1032017-c131-4fe0-a045-1d342bc56410}
```

Does the emulator requires a partition to be set even for smaller DBs? If so, how can I set one?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

I did a test for your sample,it works for me. You could remove the PartitionKey settings because you said your collection is single collection, not partitioned collection. No need to pointing any partition key.

My code:

```
DocumentClient documentClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey);

var documentLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseId, collectionId, "a1032017-c131-4fe0-a045-1d342bc56410");

await documentClient.DeleteDocumentAsync(documentLink, null);
```

Comment: Hi jay, I get an exception when calling DeleteDocumentAsync if I remove the undefined partition key: "PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation"